# i created an alarm manager to start a notification has no syntax errors but notification doesnt appear

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I tried to set a notification at a particular time and repeat it after every 24 hours. the service doesn't start or repeat when I run my code. could I be doing it all wrong ?

here is the code for the alarm manager

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr;
PendingIntent alarmIntent;
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, myService.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // Set the alarm to start at 8:30 a.p.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

    // setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
    // after 24 hours minutes.
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*60*24, alarmIntent);
```

here is the class for the service that contains the code for the notification

```
public class myService extends Service {
private NotificationManager nManager;
private static int HELLO_ID;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
   super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
{
   super.onStart(intent, startId);

   String ns = this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
   NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

   int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;        
   CharSequence tickerText = "Hello"; // ticker-text
   long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         
   Context context = getApplicationContext();     
   CharSequence contentTitle = "Hello";  
   CharSequence contentText = "Hello";      
   Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
   PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
   Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
   notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

   // and this
   HELLO_ID = 1;
   mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

the notification fails to start and fails to repeat. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Alarm Manager Documentation say's :

> This class provides access to the system alarm services. These allow
>   you to schedule your application to be run at some point in the
>   future. When an alarm goes off, the Intent that had been registered
>   for it is broadcast by the system

The intent  need to be registered with alarm.The system will broadcast intent, when alarm goes off, and code inside the broadcast receiver's onReceive() method will be executed. If you want to perform some long time task then use service to do that. Here are quick steps to setup Alarm functionality in your application:

Step1: Create Broadcast receiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         //start service. It is better to use service to perform long time    task
    }
}
```

Step2: Set alarm

```
 Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent =          PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
 AlarmManager  alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmMgr .setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```